# How do we convert jQuery parent() to VanillaJS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to convert jQuery parent(), next() and find() methods to VanillaJS

```
jQuery(event.target).parents().next('td').find('span')
```

Thanks!

Comment: See http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: @PakkuDon Yes, But any idea to do above VanillaJS conversion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention `.parent()` at Question title though `.parents()` is used at code, which are two different methods

```
let next = e.target.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
while (next.tagName !== "TD") next = next.nextElementSibling;
let span = next.querySelectorAll("span");
```